# $A$ has 8 coins and $B$ has *10* coins, what is the probability $B$ will throw more heads than $A$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I know the easier version of this, which is when $A$ has $9$ (or $n$) coins and $B$ has $10$ (or $n+1$) coins; then we may use symmetry to conclude $1/2$ (since the probability that $B$ has more heads than $A$ is equal by symmetry to the probability that $B$ has more *tails* than $A$ and the two are mutually exclusive and cover all possibilities).

But now that there's a difference of $2$ between them, we can't use the same logic anymore. Notably, it is possible to have both more heads and more tails than $A$ at the same time.

Something I've tried:

First restrict yourself to $B$'s first $9$ coins. Using the logic above, the probability that $B$ scores more heads *within the first $9$ tosses* than $A$ is $1/2$.

Now consider the probability that $B$ scores (*within the first $9$ tosses*) equally many heads as $A$.

$P(\text{# of heads in first $9$ of $B$ = # of heads in $A$}) = P(\text{# of tails in first $9$ of B = # of tails in A + 1)}$

This can be calculated as: $\sum_{i = 0}^n P(\text{A has $i$ tails})P(\text{B has $i+1$ tails}) = \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}0.5^n {n+1 \choose i}0.5^{n+1} = 0.5^{2n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}{n+1 \choose i}$

Then the total probability would be:

$P(\text{$B$ scores more heads in the first $9$ coin tosses}) + P(\text{$B$ scores equally many heads in the first $9$ tosses}) P(\text{$B$'s final toss is a head})$

$ = 0.5 + 0.5^{2n+2} \sum_{i = 0}^n {n \choose i} {n+1 \choose i}$

Oh, and $n = 8$ above.

I put this in a [Wolphram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=0.5+%2B+Power%5B0.5%2C18%5D%5C%2840%29Sum%5B%5C%2840%298+choose+i%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%299+choose+i%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bi%2C0%2C8%7D%5D%5C%2841%29) and got $0.592735$.

But given the structure of the question I feel like there should be some easier, cleverer way of doing this similar to the $n, n+1$ question.

Is there a way to leverage symmetry or some other neat property here?

Comment: That's not what python simulation would mean. Python simulation would be if you used the random number generator to simulate dice; then carry out lots of (8,10) experiments to estimate the probability

Comment: Yes, you're right. The image wasn't mine; I just saw it from someone else who attempted this problem and did this 'simulation'. I didn't check what he did. I'll take it down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a clever argument.

Let $X$ be the number of heads that $A$ throws, and let $Y$ be the number of heads that $B$ throws. Since $Y$ is equidistributed with $10-Y$, the probability of the event
$$
Y>X
$$
is the same as the probability of the event
$$
10-Y>X.
$$
But this is just the probability that $X+Y<10$, or in other words, the probability that there are at most $9$ heads among the flips of $18$ coins. By symmetry, the probability there are at most $9$ heads when $18$ coins are flipped is
$$
\frac12\left[1 + \frac1{2^{18}}\binom{18}9\right]
$$

This is essentially the same as the case where $A$ has $n$ coins and $B$ has $n+1$ coins. When you do the same trick, the result is the probability that $X+Y<n+1$, which by symmetric is $1/2$.